# Where is Gluon?

Tags: plasticscm

Gluon is mentioned prominently in the documentation and looks like it might be useful for our art team. Should be simple, right? It's not, I cannot find how to enable or install this mysterious vaporous product named Gluon.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.plasticscm.com/gluon) what you're looking for?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gluon is installed by default with every Plastic installation. You can open it via the Windows app menu or just open "gluon.exe" in the Plastic installation folder.

Comment: Yes, thanks for answering. Shortly after I posted this question in a discussion with a co-worker who pointed out that Gluon is installed alongside Plastic. Embarrassed doesn't begin to describe my reaction.